# How can I test STDERR with Test::More?

Tags: perl, file-io, dup

I am writing some tests using `Test::More`, and one of the functions I'm testing prints to `STDERR`. I'd like to test the output to `STDERR`, but am a little unsure how to do this. I know I'm close. This works:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

close STDERR;
open STDERR, ">", \my $error_string;

say STDERR "This is my message";
say qq(The \$error_string is equal to "$error_string");
```

This prints out:

```
The $error_string is equal to "This is my message
"
```

However, I don't want to close STDERR. I merely want to dup it.

I've tried this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

open my $error_fh, ">", my $error_string;
open STDERR, ">&", $error_fh;

say STDERR "This is my message";
close $error_fh;
say qq(The \$error_string is equal to "$error_string");
```

But, `$error_string` is blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, `open STDERR, ">&", $error_fh` (along with `open STDERR, ">&" . fileno($error_fh)`) does not return a true value. I think the `>&` mode might be a pretty direct syntactic sugar for a `dup` system call, which wouldn't work on a pseudo-filehandle like `$error_fh`.

How about localizing `STDERR`?

```
{
    local *STDERR = *$error_fh;
    say STDERR "something";
}
# STDERR restored
```

Comment: Dang. I thought I had `use autodie;` turned on. When I do add it, I get `Can't open 'GLOB(0x7fcb82829808)' with mode '>&': 'Bad file descriptor' at ./test.pl line 11`. Localizing STDERR should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

[Test::Output](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Test::Output) can do it, and it now uses [Capture::Tiny](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Capture::Tiny) to catch the edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

```
#  perl -MPerlIO::tee -MData::Printer -e 'my $output; STDERR->push_layer(tee=> \$output); warn "Danger, Will Robinson!"; p($output);'
Danger, Will Robinson! at -e line 1.
"Danger, Will Robinson! at -e line 1.
"
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years after this question, [Test2](https://metacpan.org/dist/Test2-Suite) came out which eventually replaced Test::More (Test::More is simply a wrapper over Test2 now). So testing STDERR nowadays is done simply with [Test2::Tools::Warnings](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test2::Tools::Warnings).

```
like(
    warning { warn 'my error' },
    qr/my error/,
    "Got expected warning"
);
```